# php mysqli date -1 month

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

here's my case. I have a table named License_expiration wherein I put the expiration date of the license. 
My problem is how do I get the expiration date -1 month to display into my dashboard table? im using html&css + php + mysql(mysqli).

ex. 2018/04/29 - expiration date. it should appear on the table when its 2018/03/29

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to exactly display. The date you entered or the difference between the date Like 1 days, two days, 1 Month, 2 month

Comment: i'm sorry if I confused you. what I want is to display the date when it has a month left before it expires.

Comment: use if else. minus the today time and expiration date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $expiration  = '2018/04/29'; //fetch the expiration on the database in
    $today = date('Y/m/d');

    //convert to strtotime;
    $convertExp = strtotime($expiration);
    $convertDay = strtotime($today);

   $timeleft = $convertExp - $convertDay;

   $daysleft = round((($timeleft/24)/60)/60); 

   if($daysleft <= 30){
    //display result here
   }else {
   //display none;
   }
```

if you want to display multiple. add it inside while loop when fetching data in the database.

Comment: I made a different approach using if else but you gave me the idea to use it. Thanks! Its working now. It shows if the license is expired or not, how many days before it's expired and how many days have passed since it expired.

Answer (score 0):

by this you can get the expiration date after 30 days

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Kolkata');
         $date = date('Y-m-d', time());
         $expdate = date('Y-m-d', time()-(30*86400));
```

check the today's date is equal to $expdate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to get your expiry date from your License_expiration table, you can use php to compare your expiration date(s) with current date

```
<?php
    $row['expiration'] = '2018/04/7'; // get your data from query
    $alert = new DateTime($row['expiration']);
    $alert->modify( '-1 month' );
    $now = new DateTime();
    if ($now > $alert) {
        // show expiration date only when less than one month
        echo $row['expiration'];
    }
```

If you have more than one expiration date then you can try this instead

```
// mysql select statement
"SELECT `expiration`, DATE_SUB(expiration, INTERVAL 1 month) AS alert FROM License_expiration"

<?php
    $now = new DateTime();
    WHILE ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $alert = new DateTime($row['alert']);
        if ($now > $alert) {
            // show expiration date only when less than one month
            echo $row['expiration'];
        }
    }
```

If your date format is 2018-04-29, then simply:

```
<?php
    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    WHILE ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($now > $row['alert']) {
                // show expiration date only when less than one month
                echo $row['expiration'];
        }
    }
```